# List all files touched by commits in git

Tags: git, git-diff, git-log

How to list all the files that were "touched" somewhere between two commits? I am looking for a command similar to `git diff COMMIT1..COMMIT2 --name-only` but including the files that were modified and reverted later.

For example, let's say I have a repository with a series of commits (linear history): C0<-C1<-C2<-C3<-C4. The commit C1 introduced a new file F and then the commit C3 removed it from the repository. I am looking for a command that, given C0 and C4, would tell me that somewhere in between there was a file F. Even though there is no such file in C0 and in C4. Therefore `git diff` wouldn't mention file F at all.

Comment: Small aside: your example has the arrows forwards, which for Git is backwards. That is, `C4` actually points to `C3`; `C3` points to `C2`, not `C4`; and so on. A branch name in Git points to the *last* commit that we wish to claim is "part of" the branch, and Git works backwards from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff ref1 ref2` takes into account only given commits, yes, but `git log` will find the missing steps and list files for each one, which `sort` will aggregate :

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only COMMIT1..COMMIT2 | sort -u
```

Comment: You most likely meant `--pretty=` and not `--pretty-format=""`.

Comment: @fluffy Thanks for the watchful eye! Written too hastily. Edited.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but `--pretty=` and `--pretty=format:""` are slightly different: the latter produces an extra empty line.

Comment: @fluffy: `--pretty` takes a *name* (short, medium, full, fuller, etc), which then produces the format, and you can define your own formats in your Git config; `--pretty=format:...` and `--pretty=tformat:...` specify the format directly. So these go through fairly different code paths. The newline is introduced by `format` but not by `tformat`. It's a bit odd since `tformat` ensures that things are terminated by newlines if needed (!). (NB: to define your own `--pretty` formats, use `pretty.foo=%h %ae %s` for instance, and then `--pretty=foo` uses that.)

Comment: @torek Pretty formats in config. How on earth did I miss that? Great suggestion.

Comment: For some reason, it's quite obscure. I don't see people use it often. (I don't use it myself.)

Comment: I finally settled on `--pretty=format:` which is the shortest I found with correct results. (I've had odd differences with the output of `--pretty=` in *some* cases so I avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

try `git log` to find the missing steps
maybe
`git log --pretty=format:"" --name-only commit1..commit2` | `sort -u`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).